# What is a colorful non-profane synonym for "batshit crazy"?

Tags: phrase-requests

I would like to describe something (that I did) as batshit crazy, but that term may not be appropriate in my workplace. (I'm a college professor.) Is there a vivid but non-profane synonym? Even better would be a term that doesn't reference mental illness. (I'm a liberal arts college professor.)

Ten years ago, I would have used the term "ridonculous".

Comment: Just say you're *stir-crazy*. It's obviously apropos and people will understand.

Comment: How about [harebrained](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/harebrained), meaning rash, foolish, or badly thought out?

Comment: @Mick- *stir crazy* means something completely different.  It refers to the pent up need to get out of a confining environment whether that is a jail cell or a snowed in cabin, etc.

Comment: You could do something *crazy*, or something *really crazy* or something *really, really crazy*.  you could do something *outlandish*.

Comment: You went a little [Daffy Duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daffy_Duck)

Comment: Out of his mind, off his knocker, few cards short of a full deck -- we have no shortage of colorful turns of phrase to describe being stark raving mad. Bat-shit crazy does imply mental illness (or, at minimum, insanity) in my experience so I'm not too clear what you're after.

Comment: I fail to see how one can stick to the idea of batshit crazy without "referencing" "mental illness". The last time I "looked", the idea is ***lunatic***. Originally, from that Greco-Roman bag of cultural tricks for those who are out of sorts with lunar phases and who display instability. Isn't the sub-text to your post is: political correctness at all cost, even to the extent of denying human experience?

Comment: It would help to know the nature of the incident.  Did you act without fear?  As a child?  etc..

Comment: Looney toons. Off their rocker. Bats in the belfry. Crazy as a loon ...

Comment: You could always just use "batty".

Comment: You need an adjective to describe the thing, not the person doing the thing, if I understood right.  You want it to sound fresh and extreme.  Here are some ideas: tomfool (old-fashioned enough to sound fresh), bugged out, way-out weird (the alliteration hopefully strengthens the effect), wacko (from Car Talk), horse's behind crazy, freaked, diffy daffy.  Not sure if these are extreme enough.

Answer (score 2):

Batshit crazy is lunatic, perforce, of the moon. Adjective: lunatical

Love's Labour's Lost
[V, 1]

Holofernes

1750

He draweth out the thread of his verbosity finer 
than the staple of his argument. I abhor such 
fanatical phantasimes, such insociable and 
point-devise companions; such rackers of 
orthography, as to speak dout, fine, when he should 
say doubt; det, when he should pronounce debt,—d, 
e, b, t, not d, e, t: he clepeth a calf, cauf; 
half, hauf; neighbour vocatur nebor; neigh 
abbreviated ne. This is abhominable,—which he 
would call abbominable: it insinuateth me of 
insanie: anne intelligis, domine? **to make frantic, lunatic**.

Dear Professor, do, I pray, feed that to your students. :)

2

Love's Labour's Lost
[II, 1]

Rosaline

550

Another of these students at that time 
Was there with him, if I have heard a truth. 
Biron they call him; but a merrier man, 
Within the limit of becoming mirth, 
I never spent an hour's talk withal: 
His eye begets occasion for his wit; 
For every object that the one doth catch 
**The other turns to a mirth-moving jest, 
Which his fair tongue, conceit's expositor, 
Delivers in such apt and gracious words 
That aged ears play truant at his tales 
And younger hearings are quite ravished**; [effect of  political correctness??]
So sweet and voluble is his discourse.

In other words, kids, grow up.

Answer (score 2):

Consider

[irrational](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/irrational) [OXD],

> Not logical or reasonable

[unreasonable](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unreasonable) [OXD],

> Not guided by or based on good sense.

[ill-advised](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ill-advised) [OXD], or

> Not sensible, wise, or prudent.

[bonkers](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bonkers) [OXD]

> Mad; crazy.

Comment: I like "bonkers". The others aren't colorful.

Answer (score 0):

Let's substitute **guano crazy** for the OP's *batshit crazy.* Not quite so profane as the OP.

**Guano:** is the accumulated excrement of seabirds, seals or cave-dwelling **bats** [emphasis added] (Wikipedia)

Answer (score 0):

The term that comes to mind is 'meteorically eccentric'. The effectiveness of that, however, will depend upon your delivery; if it's written, delivery shouldn't be a problem, but if it's spoken, poise, skilled control of intonation, and timing, will all be central to the phrase's communicative value.

The original, 'batshit crazy', is not an especially worthwhile phrase to start. It relies primarily on shock value, which is undermined by its contemporary familiarity: 'batshit' only serves as an intensifier for 'crazy'. In literal senses, *batshit* is hugely important, and not at all *crazy*.

The most straightforward senses of 'meteorically' and 'eccentric' communicated by your phrase would of course be figurative, and because you alone know what you're describing (other than the general sense), it might well be that you could think of a more apt metaphor or simile.

Of 'meteorically eccentric', the nuanced oxymoronic play on literal and figurative senses bolsters the effect. The usual figurative use of meteoric to suggest a rapid rise (in career, reputation, etc.), will always be contradicted by the (literal) experience afforded by personal observations on earth, where meteors are known to fall.

Here is the sense of 'meteorically' intended:

> **meteorically**, *adv.*
>   Like a meteor; with the suddenness and speed of a meteor.
>
> ["meteorically, adv.". OED Online. September 2016. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/117473?redirectedFrom=meteorically (accessed October 31, 2016).]

Of 'eccentric', figurative and literal senses should be simultaneously in play. The literal, loosely astronomical sense is provoked by the word being modified by another astronomical term ('meteorically'):

> **eccentric**, *adj.* and *n.*
>   ....
>   **5. a.** Of orbital motion: Not referable to a fixed centre of revolution; ....
>   ....
>   **b.** *transf.* Of a heavenly body: Moving in an orbit deviating (more or less) from a circle.
>   ....
>   **6.** *fig.* Regulated by no central control.
>   **a.** Of actions, movements, and things in general: Irregular, anomalous, proceeding by no known method, capricious.
>   ....
>   **b.** Of persons and personal attributes: Deviating from usual methods, odd, whimsical.
>
> ["eccentric, adj. and n.". OED Online. September 2016. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/59245?redirectedFrom=eccentric (accessed October 31, 2016).]

It should be noted that 'eccentricity', in figurative senses, is ambivalently appreciated. It does not, however, have a necessary relation to mental illness.